# Querying indexed data on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I had indexed data on elastic search  with terms like "name",and "message". Now I want to apply query on indexed data in such a way that I want to find frequency (count) of a certain pharse used in the message. For example messages are "I like to eat sandwich","I like to eat burger" etc,,,Now i want to query that how many times "like to" pharse is used in all the indexed messages.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the Terms Facet API.
See here : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html

You can filter your facet with a specific term if you need too. See "Facet Filter" on the following page : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/index.html

HTH
David.